# Populate DataTable with records from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, vb.net, methods

This is my GET Method to get my data from my DataTable

```
Private Function GetData() As PagedDataSource
' Declarations    
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim dr As DataRow
Dim pg As New PagedDataSource

' Add some columns    
dt.Columns.Add("Column1")
dt.Columns.Add("Column2")

' Add some test data    
For i As Integer = 0 To 10
    dr = dt.NewRow
    dr("Column1") = i
    dr("Column2") = "Some Text " & (i * 5)
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
Next

' Add a DataView from the DataTable to the PagedDataSource  
pg.DataSource = dt.DefaultView

' Return the DataTable    
Return pg 
End Function
```

It returns the DataTable as "pg"

What changes must I make to this GET method to get the records from a table in my database?

C# examples will also do but would be great to see a reply with my code and then the changes....

Comment: For this kind of things I use Linq-To-Sql or on heavy projects NHibernate. Consider using a ORM...

Comment: I cant use LINQ because it is a 2.0 Project....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If Linq to SQL is not an option then you can fall back to ADO.NET. Essentially you will need to create a connection to your database and create and run a command to retrieve the data you require and populate a DataTable. Here is an example if C#:

```
// Create a connection to the database        
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MyDBServer;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True");
// Create a command to extract the required data and assign it the connection string
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Column1, Colum2 FROM MyTable", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
// Create a DataAdapter to run the command and fill the DataTable
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```